# Android Emulator : PANIC could not open in Bamboo CI Server

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator, bamboo

I'm trying to configure my CI server (Bamboo) to run tests on virtual device.
In one of tasks I have shell scrip that creates virtual device and then try to run it. But emulator says PANIC: Could not open:

Is there any flag that I can pass to emulator and see detailed logs about error?

Here is my script

```
# Android SDK Location
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux

# Name of virtual device
AVD_NAME=ANDROID_19_HVGA

# File that will be used for writing emulator logs
AVD_LOG_FILE=/tmp/android_avd_${AVD_NAME,,}.log

# Get list of available virtual devices
avd_list=$($ANDROID_HOME/tools/android list avd -c)

echo $avd_list

# Check if there is available virtual devices
if [ ! "$avd_list" ]; then
    # Creating Virtual Device
    $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android create avd --name $AVD_NAME -t 2 -d 14 --sdcard 128M -p ~/.android/avd/$AVD_NAME
    $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android list avd
fi

stdbuf -o0 $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd $AVD_NAME -no-window -no-audio -no-boot-anim -port 5554 -debug-init 1> $AVD_LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
sleep 5

has_error=`cat $AVD_LOG_FILE | grep PANIC`

if [ "$has_error" ]; then
    echo "Error opening emulator $AVD_NAME"
    exit 1;
fi

echo Waiting for emulator
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device
```